# Missing Rspec Core

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

Here is the message that I have been getting when running rspec:
`/home/patrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@rails3tutorial/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:386:in load: no such file to load -- /spec (LoadError)`

My .gemfile looks like this:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.3'  
gem 'sqlite3-ruby', '1.3.2', :require => 'sqlite3'  
gem 'gravatar_image_tag', '1.0.0.pre2'  
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.pre2'  

group :development do  
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.3.0'  
  gem 'annotate-models', '1.0.4'  
  gem 'faker', '0.3.1'  
end  

group :test do  
  gem 'rspec', '2.3.0'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.3.0'   
  gem 'webrat', '0.7.1'  
  gem 'spork', '0.8.4'  
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '1.0'  
end
```

As you can see it appears it is trying to load rpsec 2.5.1, however I have specified version 2.3.0.

I am working on the tutorial from railstutorial.org and I am working on Chapter 5, if that helps.

Comment: Have you tried to specify `rspec-rails` for the group `test` yet?

Comment: What command are you using to run rspec. You may want to try: bundle exec if you're not getting the bundled version of rspec.

Comment: I am using `rspec /spec` as the tutorial instructs. In addition, I did try `bundle exec rspec /spec` and got the same error.

Comment: That leading slash is throwing you off -- try `rspec spec`

Comment: Tried without the leading slash and got this error after running bundle install as instructed: `/home/patrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/ui.rb:56:in <class:UI>: uninitialized constant Gem::SilentUI (NameError)
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer: my layout_links_spec.rb had a missing `=` in a test. Thanks for trying though!

Answer (score 0):

For me with same problem I saw that in Gemfile it was supposed to use one version, and in the error backtrace another - and it worked to `gem unistall` the one that wasn't mentioned in `Gemfile.lock`